# How to group by columns, and pick arbitrary non null other columns to display

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a staging table with new address records and need to copy new cities into a mart table. I want to only have one entry in the mart for each city, state, zip combination, and I want to include latitude and longitude for the city. The address table has lat & long, but they could be anywhere within the city, or could be null.

The query I've got so far gets me the right data, but it's pulling one pair of lat & long arbitrarily. I'd prefer to pull from the ones that are not null.

```
SELECT a.city
  ,a.STATE
  ,a.country
  ,a.latitude
  ,a.longitude
FROM (
  SELECT city
    ,STATE
    ,country
  FROM staging2.address_daily s
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM mart.city m
      WHERE m.city_name = s.city
        AND m.state_code = s.STATE
        AND m.country_code = s.country
      )
  GROUP BY city
    ,STATE
    ,country
  ) sq --This subquery groups by city state and country
JOIN staging2.address_daily a
  ON a.ID = (
      SELECT ID
      FROM staging2.address_daily i
      WHERE i.city = sq.city
        AND i.STATE = sq.STATE
        AND i.country = sq.country LIMIT 1
      ) --This subquery takes the group, and picks one ID. 
--The overall query is still flawed, as we're picking at random, and we should ideally pick a non-null latitude and longitude if they exist.
```

I'm using MySQL but would prefer to avoid things that are unique to MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a SQL perspective this logic would work. For MySQL you might need to do some tweaks to the syntax -

```
SELECT sq.city
  ,sq.STATE
  ,sq.country
  ,a.latitude
  ,a.longitude
FROM (
  SELECT city
    ,STATE
    ,country
  FROM staging2.address_daily s
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM mart.city m
      WHERE m.city_name = s.city
        AND m.state_code = s.STATE
        AND m.country_code = s.country
      )
  GROUP BY city
    ,STATE
    ,country
  ) sq --This subquery groups by city state and country
LEFT JOIN staging2.address_daily a
  ON a.ID = (
      SELECT ID
      FROM staging2.address_daily i
      WHERE i.city = sq.city
        AND i.STATE = sq.STATE
        AND i.country = sq.country 
        AND NOT latitude IS NULL LIMIT 1
      )
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems pretty obvious now that I look at it. I'll make sure it works in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this to see if it works for you

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT city,
               STATE,
               country,
               A.latitude,
               A.longitude,
               ROW_NUMBER ()
               OVER (PARTITION BY city, state, country
                     ORDER BY longitude, latitude DESC)
                  AS ROWNUM
          FROM staging2.address_daily s
         WHERE NOT EXISTS
                      (SELECT *
                         FROM mart.city M
                        WHERE     M.city_name = s.city
                              AND M.state_code = s.STATE
                              AND M.country_code = s.country))
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```